# Mirror Win10 OS with boot?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, mirroring

I have a MX100 512GB which is showing signs of failure and as such I ordered a new MX500 500GB.

I've been browsing around how to mirror one HD to the other including the boot so I can simple replace one with the other but all I see is that you can mirror using windows but that you have to do dynamic disk(or something) and doing so both HD's will not be bootable.

I am not changing any hardware on the computer or putting the HD on a different computer, it will be a 1:1 replacement of HD.

**How can I mirror the old HD into the new one including the boot so that I can simple replace one with the other and have everything work just as it was before?**

Comment: Thought it might be possible to run some sort of hardware RAID setup, between trying to preserve the data, the different disk sizes, and the general principal that RAID arrays aren't for this purpose, I don't think it makes sense to try this. Instead, I'd recommend just switching the drive out now. Also, always make sure you have good working backups.

Comment: I haven't had much luck with cloning software. Others have done it with zero or little issues. You can try this out: https://lifehacker.com/how-to-migrate-to-a-solid-state-drive-without-reinstall-5837543 or this: https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html?hot=true&from=en_nav_free-tools

Comment: @JMY1000 yeah I do have backups but there is this one thing I always have to do after re-installing the whole system which takes time and is really annoying which basically is, reinstalling all the applications, placing em back to their config state that I often use, placements of things, re-organizing the 3 monitors and where things goes in,and list goes on... I just want to avoid to have to do these by cloning it [I've finally found this article which seems to be simple enough](https://www.maketecheasier.com/clone-windows-10-drive/) which I will try tomorrow

Comment: @Jatmin thx I've seen macrium a couple times but since it was also paid I was too afraid I might need something that is from the paid features and be left in the middle of the process with it.

Comment: @Guapo I've had success with cloning applications. Acronis True Image has been my personal favorite on Windows, and it offers a free 30 day trial. If you prefer free software, Clonezilla is licensed under the GPL, and should work as well.

Comment: @JMY1000 thanks for reassuring me, I've got a disk with clonezilla ready just waiting for the new ssd to arrive to try and if it doesn't goes as expected I will try Acronis.